# Syntax for defining members of template template class

Tags: c++, templates

Can anyone please tell what is syntax for defining member of template template class.

```
 template< template <typename T > class U, class T >
 class Z
 {
     static void dispatcher();
 };

 template< template <typename T > class U, class T >
 void Z< U >::dispatcher();
 {

 }
```

I am getting too few arguments error on using above syntax.

Comment: The template declares two types, but `Z<U>` only uses one. Where is the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template has two types: `U` and `T`.

You need to use both of them like

```
 void Z< U, T >::dispatcher()
```

Also you have an errant `;` at then end of

```
void Z< U >::dispatcher();
```

Comment: Thanks realized it now

Comment: Do you need to specify the parameter on the parameter? (ie. `void Z<U<T>,T>::dispatcher()`)? I'm curious...

Comment: @callyalater No.  It should be in a deduced context.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've seen it like that before, but I was unsure about it.